# Ruby Array trouble

Tags: ruby, arrays

Unexpected for me the *array* in output has ["89"] value, instead of expected ["123456","89"]. Why is this happening?

```
string = ""
array = []
10.times { |i|
    if i != 7  
        string  << "#{i}" 
    else 
        array << string
        string.clear 
    end
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect the answer to be `["123456","89"]`? You've only added the string to the array once, so the array will only contain one string. Also, the array holds the string by reference, not by value, so when you did `string.clear`, it would also affect the string in the array.

Comment: Why do you expect that output? What happened with zero?

Comment: Add `p string; p array` to the end of the method and you will see what happens every step. Notice that after you have added the string to the array it is only added as a reference, and and changes to the sring will also be changed in the array.

Comment: Ok, i understood why array will contain only one string. So, can i push a string in array by variable without any references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do

```
string.clear
```

You are just changing the referenced string, which is why that `0123456` that you pushed into the array initially suddenly became an `89` afterwards.

You probably want

```
string = ""
```